# build warnings?

Tags: android, compilation

I get the following warnings whenever I build my android project.

```
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'. 
Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.  
Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.  
Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.    
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
```

I checked my Gradle file and based on Android Studio's suggestions,  replaced the **Compile** directive with **Implementation** directive.

The app works fine now but I would like to handle these warnings.

EDIT:
my gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shaitest.testcam"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

The warnings mean just exactly what they say.

The directives are now obsolete (***no longer used or outdated***). In place of them, Android has new directives which Android Studio has suggested for you to use.

By replacing them with the new directives, you have handled the warnings correctly.

Comment: I changed the directives and still I get these warnings....,  that means something else is wrong and I really have no idea what it is.

Comment: Maybe you could share your build.gradle(app)

Answer (score 0):

You have answer in your question itself you need to change **androidTestCompile** with **androidTestImplementation** and other warnings as mentioned.

Check documentation for more details https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration